# Equality of ideals involving products of ideals

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $A = \sqrt{-6}$, I need to show $\langle 2 \rangle = \langle 2, A\rangle*\langle 2, A\rangle$ and $\langle 3 \rangle = \langle 3, A \rangle*\langle 3, A\rangle$. I am using * to emphasize the product of the ideals. Certainly any help with one will carry over to the other so lets look at the first one. It is obvious that $\langle 2 \rangle$ is a subset of $\langle 2, A \rangle$. That is where I get stuck. To show the opposite inclusion I need to express an arbitrary element of the product, $\langle 2, A \rangle*\langle 2, A\rangle$ as a multiple of $2$. This is where I fall short.

Comment: What are these ideals of?

Comment: @Loki I should have mentioned that we are working in K = Q(sqrt(-6)). (and yes, I still haven't learned LaTex!)

Comment: So these are ideals of the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in a commutative ring, $<x,y>^2=<x^2,xy,y^2>.$ So $<2,\sqrt{6}>^2=<4,2\sqrt{6},6>=<2,2\sqrt{6}>.$

$$<x,y>=\{r_1x+r_2y |r_1,r_2 \in R \},$$

$$<x,y>^2=\{ a_1b_1+a_2b_2 | a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2 \in <x,y> \}$$
$$= \{ (r_{1,1}x+r_{1,2}y)(r_{2,1}x+r_{2,2}y)+(r_{3,1}x+r_{3,2}y)(r_{4,1}x+r_{4,2}y) | r_{i,j} \in R \}$$
$$=\{ r_{1,1}r_{2,1}x^2+r_{1,2}r_{2,1}xy+r_{1,1}r_{2,2}xy+r_{1,2}r_{2,2}y^2+r_{3,1}r_{4,1}x^2+r_{3,2}r_{4,1}xy+r_{3,1}r_{4,2}xy+r_{3,2}r_{4,2}y^2 | r_{i,j} \in R \}$$
$$=\{ (r_{1,1}r_{2,1}+r_{3,1}r_{4,1})x^2+(r_{1,2}r_{2,1}+r_{1,1}r_{2,2}+r_{3,2}r_{4,1}+r_{3,1}r_{4,2})xy+(r_{1,2}r_{2,2}+r_{3,2}r_{4,2})y^2 | r_{i,j} \in R \}$$
$$=\{ r_{1,1}x^2+(r_{1,2}+r_{3,1})xy+r_{3,2}y^2 | r_{i,j} \in R \}$$
$$=<x^2,xy,y^2>.$$